# Why is UIPanGestureRecognizer not working at the top portion of the screen in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I created a UIPanGestureRecognizer in a UICollectionViewCell subclass. It works in all cells except the top of the screen. About the height of status bar the pan gesture recognizer is dead. It doesn't fire. My test app only has a UICollectionView and nothing else. No status bar. I think maybe it has to do with the notification center "active edge" stealing touch events.

```
_panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureRecognized:)];
_panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
_panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[self addGestureRecognizer:_panGestureRecognizer];
```

At the top of screen when I pan in the cell I get no message upon pan begin. There is no call to the callback until I lift the finger. Then the callback receives BEGAN and immediately after that it receives ENDED.

```
- (void)panGestureRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    NSLog(@"pan detected"); // for first cell, only called when finger is lifted up.

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"BEGAN");
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"ENDED");
    }
}
```

The cell is the delegate of the gesture recognizer. It implements:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

The cell also overwrites the UIView method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Is this a known problem with pan gesture recognizers at the top of the screen? And is there a workaround?

Comment: I think you answered your own question..

Comment: 0x7fffffff No I did not. I think you have no idea why the gesture recognizer callback does not receive a propper cancelled state and thus you downvoted my good question.

Comment: Why do you assume I down voted your question. You asked this 21 minutes ago, and were down voted two minutes later. I didn't come across this post until about 10 minutes later when I left my comment...

Comment: Had the same problem, fixed it. See my own answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495796/uiscrollview-uipangesturerecognizer-dead-zone-on-top-edge-of-screen/19502826#19502826

Comment: Hope someone can solve the problem.