# UIScrollView UIPangestureRecognizer dead zone on top edge of screen

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

as shown in the picture below the UIPanGestureRecognizer will not pan when the drag started inside the "dead zone" on the top of the screen. This is most likely caused by the notification center.

[image]

The touchesMoved:withEvent: method however does get called, so there should be a way to get pan gestures recognized in this area.

Has anyone else came across this issue, are there any workarounds out there yet? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. The touchesMoved:withEvent: should be implemented this way:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches.allObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    CGPoint contentOffset = self.contentOffset;

    contentOffset.x -= location.x - previousLocation.x;
    [self setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Met the same problem.This may solve your problem.But it's best to do something for the dead zone to response normally.Hope some one could find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that on the top edge of the screen you have multiple gesture recognisers that interferes. It could be that the the other gesture recogniser that interferes is added by system with some UIElement.

Try to implement **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** on your gesture recogniser delegate.

Especially this method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{

     NSLog(@"1st recognizer class: %@ ; 2nd recognizer class: %@", NSStringFromClass([gestureRecognizer class]), NSStringFromClass([otherGestureRecognizer class])); 

     return YES; 

}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:

Comment: Thanks maros. I did implement all the delegate methods, including this one returning YES. I also tried to get all the superviews and remove their gestureRecognizers, without any success. It seems like the notification center recognizers can't be accessed in any way.

Comment: Ok, with the logging I found out that there is a "UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer" which most likely causes the issue. This one seems to ignore the return value though.